# How to change umask so all files start with different modal bits than new directories

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, umask

Specifiacally, I need to give files rw----r--
and dirs rwx--xr-x

Comment: That is not possible by a specific `umask` setting alone. The mask only masks, it does not define the final permissions. I suggest you start reading the documentation of that command. Easiest by starting to read the manual page: `man umask`. Then, as a next step, try around a little. That is not rocket science ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `umask 062`.

This works because `umask` only unsets bits, and files aren't normally created with executable bits set in the first place:

```
$ umask 062
$ touch myfile; mkdir mydir
$ ls -ld myfile mydir
drwx--xr-x 1 user user 0 Dec  5 15:21 mydir
-rw----r-- 1 user user 0 Dec  5 15:21 myfile
```